# BAT/CMD to launch a exe multiple times with different parameters without extra bat files

Tags: batch-file, windows-command-prompt

Have a bat that calls a single exe for say 5-10 functions. Is there a way to make the executable run in multiple processes from a bat or cmd? for example:

```
  start cmd /k 
   cd Program files\Prog\Happy
   happy.exe optimize 113 /nointerupt >NuL &
   happy.exe optimize 114 /nointerupt >NuL &
   happy.exe optimize 115 /nointerupt >NuL &
   happy.exe optimize 116 /nointerupt >NuL &
```

I would rather not use multiple bat files called from one bat file.
Perhaps create a separate PID for each exe....?

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to launch simultaneous multiple instances of happy.exe?

You can accomplish it using the **START** command in a single batch file:

```
start "one" happy.exe optimize 113 /nointerupt >NuL &
start "two" happy.exe optimize 114 /nointerupt >NuL &
start "three" happy.exe optimize 115 /nointerupt >NuL &
start "four" happy.exe optimize 116 /nointerupt >NuL &
```

For usage type  **start /?**